# "start": "sass./sass/style.scss style.css --watch"

Tags: css, npm, sass

I run a command `npm start`. After that I get an error. The error throws  the following error message:

```
ecommerce@1.0.0 start C:\xampp\htdocs\E-Commerce sass./sass/style.scss style.css --watch 'sass.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm    ERR! ecommerce@1.0.0 start: `sass./sass/style.scss style.css --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the    ecommerce@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem    with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MuhammadBashir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-02T12_19_09_949Z-debug.log
```

Here is my `package.json` file content:

```
    {
      "name": "ecommerce",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "sass./sass/style.scss style.css --watch"
       },
      "author": "Muhammad Bashir",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
      "node-sass": "^6.0.1"
       }
    }
```